# Coin tossing probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

A jar contains 50 type 1 coins and 50 type 2 coins.  Type 1 coins have probability 3/4 of landing on heads, while type 2 coins have probability 1/4 of landing on heads.  If a coin is chosen at random from the jar and tossed 3 times, what is the probability that it lands on heads at least 2 times?

SOLUTION:

P(H2|C1)=3(3/4)^2(1/4)

P(H2|C2)=3(1/4)^2(3/4)

P(H3|C1)=(3/4)^3

P(H3|C2)=(1/4)^3

P(H2UH3) = P(H2) + P(H3)

```
           = P(C1)P(H2|C1) + P(C2)P(H2|C2) + P(C1)P(H3|C1) + P(C2)P(H3|C2)
```

= 1/2

Comment: I will assume that at random here means that all coins are equally likely to be picked.  Let $a$ be the probability that a Type 1 coin lands heads two or more times in three tosses, and let $b$ be the corresponding probability for Type 2 coins.  Then the required probability is $(50/100)a+(50/100)b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use $P(A) = P(A \mid B) P(B) + P(A \mid B^c) P(B^c)$, where $A$ is the event that the coin lands on heads at least two times and $B$ is the event that the chosen coin is of type $1$.